# How to prevent an MDI document from being minimized

Tags: winapi, mfc

I'm maintaining a classic MDI MFC application, and I'd like to prevent the user from minimizing an MDI document window.

The best solution would be if I just could remove or disable the "Minimze" button
from the MDI Window and remove/disable the "Minimize" command from the menu that shows up when you click on the upper left corner of the MDI window.

[image]

Comment: [Using the Multiple Document Interface: Creating a Child Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644909.aspx#creating_child): *"To create an MDI child window that can have any combination of window styles, specify the **MDIS_ALLCHILDSTYLES** window style. When this style is not specified, an MDI child window has the **WS_MINIMIZE**, **WS_MAXIMIZE**, **WS_HSCROLL**, and **WS_VSCROLL** styles as default settings."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `PreCreateWindow` from `CChildFrame`, and write:

```
BOOL CChildFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
  // TODO: Modify the Window class or styles here by modifying
  //  the CREATESTRUCT cs

  cs.style &= ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX;

  if(! CMDIChildWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs))
      return FALSE;

  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Also, you can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z205k8d.aspx